# Calling release on object obtained from CFBridgingRelease

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

1. serial (a NSString *) is obtained using **CFBridgingRelease**
2. The file that has this code does not use ARC (**-fno-objc-arc**
   compiler flag)
3. **Will ARC take care of releasing this memory**,
   in-spite of the above flag,  or it must be manually released? In
   certain situation using release seems to be causing crash
   (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) and the stack-trace shows some autoreleasepool
   related code there.

---

```
NSString *serial = nil;
io_service_t platformExpert = IOServiceGetMatchingService(kIOMasterPortDefault,
                                                          IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice"));
if (platformExpert) {
    CFTypeRef serialNumberAsCFString =
    IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(platformExpert,
                                    CFSTR(kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey),
                                    kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
    if (serialNumberAsCFString) {
        serial = CFBridgingRelease(serialNumberAsCFString);
    }

    IOObjectRelease(platformExpert);
}
[serial release];
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the static analyzer (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> or choose "Analyze" on Xcode's "Product" menu) and it will tell you precisely what's wrong. And if you click on the icon next to the error message, it will show the trail of logic as to how it concluded there was an issue:

[image]

Note, as the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html) says:

> - `__bridge_retained` or `CFBridgingRetain` casts an Objective-C pointer to a Core Foundation pointer and also transfers ownership to you.
>
>   You are responsible for calling `CFRelease` or a related function to relinquish ownership of the object.
> - `__bridge_transfer` or `CFBridgingRelease` moves a non-Objective-C pointer to Objective-C and also transfers ownership to ARC.
>
>   ARC is responsible for relinquishing ownership of the object.

So, you really shouldn't be using `CFBridgingRelease` at all with non-ARC code. The `CFBridgingRelease`  available in manual reference counting "is intended for use while converting to ARC mode only." And if you look at the definition of this function in manual reference counting code, it really does an `autorelease` (simulating the clean up ARC would do for you). But as the documentation says, it's only intended while actively transitioning your code base to ARC.

But, as you can see, if that's doing an `autorelease`, and you manually `release` it as well, you're over releasing.

Bottom line, if you're writing manual reference counting code and you want to transfer ownership so you'll `release` it later, you should use `CFBridgingRetain`. If you replace `CFBridgingRelease` with `CFBridgingRetain` in your snippet and re-analyze your code, the warning will go away.

If you've written manual reference counting code, don't be disheartened when you first run the static analyzer, as you may see many issues pop up. But just plug through them, one-by-one, until you get a clean bill of health.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things, which look strange:

1. The last `[serial release];` looks strange. You have passed its value with `CFBridgingRelease()`. If you use ARC you can't send `release`. If you don't use ARC, you should set `serial` to `nil` after that, but I suppose you want use its value later. So you shouldn't release it.
2. I don't know `IOServiceGetMatchingService()` but you don't own it (see [Get Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1)). <strike>Thus, you shouldn't release it.</strike>

   **Edit**: As @Rob stated in a comment below. You're owner of the service object after all, and you must release it. Strange times we live in.

Comment: I agree with your intuition about `IOServiceGetMatchingService`, as it doesn't have `Create` or `Copy` in the name (thus the [Create Rule](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029) would not apply). But if you look at the documentation for `IOServiceGetMatchingService`, it explicitly says that it returns, "The first service matched is returned on success. The service must be released by the caller." So it apparently doesn't follow the standard Core Foundation memory rules.

Comment: Is that so? That's pretty bad.

Comment: I agree. But the IOKit header goes on to warn us "IOKit objects returned by all functions should be released with `IOObjectRelease`." #sigh

Comment: I believe you, and I'm totally with you. I've adapted my post.